# Copying lists of lists in groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to perform a copy and get two different objects so that I can work on the copy without impacting the original.

I have this code (groovy 2.0.5):

```
def a = [[1,5,2,1,1], ["one", "five", "two", "one", "one"]]
def b = a
b.add([6,6,6,6,6,6])
println a
println b
```

that produces:

```
[[1, 5, 2, 1, 1], [one, five, two, one, one], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]
[[1, 5, 2, 1, 1], [one, five, two, one, one], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]
```

seems like b and a are actually the same object

I can fix it in this way:

```
def a = [[1,5,2,1,1], ["one", "five", "two", "one", "one"]]
def b = []

a.each {
    b.add(it)
}

b.add([6,6,6,6,6])
println a
println b
```

that produces my wanted result:

```
[[1, 5, 2, 1, 1], [one, five, two, one, one]]
[[1, 5, 2, 1, 1], [one, five, two, one, one], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]
```

But now look at this, where I want the original object and a copy with unique and sorted elements:

```
def a = [[1,5,2,1,1], ["one", "five", "two", "one", "one"]]
def b = a

b.each {
    it.unique().sort()
}

println a
println b
```

that produces:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [five, one, two]]
[[1, 2, 5], [five, one, two]]
```

If I try the same fix this time it doesn't work:

```
def a = [[1,5,2,1,1], ["one", "five", "two", "one", "one"]]
def b = []

a.each { 
    b.add(it)
}

b.each {
    it.unique().sort()
}

println a
println b
```

that still produces:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [five, one, two]]
[[1, 2, 5], [five, one, two]]
```

What's going on ?

Comment: Edited title, as these are lists, not arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just calling `b = a` sets `b` to being the same instance of the list (containing the same list instances) as `a`

Calling the second method with the `a.each { b.add(it) }` means b points to a different instance of List, but the contents of `b` are the same instances of lists as in `a`

What you need is something like:

```
def b = a*.collect()

b.each {
  it.unique().sort()
}
```

So the `a*.collect()` makes a new instance of a list for each list in `a`

You can also do this in one line:

```
def b = a*.unique( false )*.sort( false )
```

Passing `false` to `unique` and `sort` [stop those method changing the original lists](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28boolean%29), and force them to return new list instances.

<sub>(Indeed the observant amongst you will notice that the `sort` does not need `false` passed to it, as we already have a new instance thanks to `unique`)</sub>

Comment: `.collectNested{}`

Answer (score 2):

Groovy has [`Collection#collectNested`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collectNested%28groovy.lang.Closure%29), which is the recursive form of [`#collect`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect%28groovy.lang.Closure%29). This will create copies of lists of arbitrary depth. Prior to version 1.8.1 it's called [`#collectAll`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collectAll%28groovy.lang.Closure%29).

```
final a = [
    'a', [ 'aa', 'ab', [ 'aba', 'abb', 'abc' ], 'ac', 'ad' ], 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
]

final b = a.collectNested { it }
b[0] = 'B'

final c = a.collectNested { it * 2 }
c[0] = 'C'

assert a as String ==
    '[a, [aa, ab, [aba, abb, abc], ac, ad], b, c, d, e]'

assert b as String ==
    '[B, [aa, ab, [aba, abb, abc], ac, ad], b, c, d, e]'

assert c as String ==
    '[C, [aaaa, abab, [abaaba, abbabb, abcabc], acac, adad], bb, cc, dd, ee]'
```